# How do I handle an exception thrown in a Blazor child component in the component/page hosting it?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How is an exception handled when thrown in a Blazor child component in the component/page hosting it?

##### Scenario

I am building a Blazor UI component that is responsible for validating login credentials (Username and Password). It validates using an authentication service. If the credentials are NOT valid, the service throws an InvalidLoginCredentialsException. I am using the "code-behind" approach and the C# looks something like this ...

```
public class LoginFormBase : PageBase
{
    // Properties
    //
    public String Username { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public String Password { get; set; } = String.Empty;


    // EventCallback to communicate the result to the parent component
    //
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<SingleSignOn> OnLogin { get; set; }
    
    // Event handler
    //
    protected void btnLogin_OnClick()
    {
        var user = this.SignOnService.Login(this.Username, this.Password); <!-- throws InvalidLoginCredentialsException
        OnLogin.InvokeAsync(user);
    }
}
```

I have a razor Component/Page which implements the LoginForm component. The UI code looks like ...

```
@page "/login";
@inherits LoginBase
@using ThriftShopTracker.Components;


<div class="container">
    
    <h1 class="display-8 mt-3 mb-2">Login</h1>
    
    <LoginForm OnLogin="@LoginForm_OnLogin"></LoginForm>

</div>
```

And the "code behind" *that* looks like ...

```
 public class LoginBase : PageBase
 {        
      protected void LoginForm_OnLogin(SingleSignOn user)
      {
          this.CurrentUser = user;
          // 
          // I WANT TO HANDLE THE EXCEPTION HERE
          //
      }
  }
```

So the problem is that when I enter the wrong credentials the exception is thrown as expected, but I want to handle it in the LoginBase code. I want to try/catch the exception so I can handle it but since the LoginForm_OnLogin() is being "Invoked" in the LoginForm component, there is nothing to catch in the LoginBase code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LoginForm` initiates the call stack.  It is not initiated by the parent form, so errors will not be thrown back up to the parent form.

You should catch the error in the `LoginForm` and then use another event to notify the parent form of the details of the error.

E.g add another event `OnLoginFailure(errorInfo)`

Comment: That was it ... Thank you very much.